# How can i make this method return to that variable in that loop

Tags: java

I want to return to `result` variable but eclipse marks that `return result;` part and says `Create local variable 'result'`.

The method i wrote:

```
 public E getFromResults(int o)
 {
     Node tempNode = head;
     for(int i=1; i<= size; i++)
     {
         if(i==o)
         {
            E result = (E) tempNode.getElement();
            break;
         }

         tempNode=tempNode.getNext();
     }

     return result;
 }
```

Okay i did it as shown below so it is working now thank you everone who answered for their help:

```
 public E getFromResults(int o)
 {
     Node tempNode = head;
     for(int i=1; i<= size; i++)
     {
         if(i==o)
            break;

         tempNode=tempNode.getNext();
     }

     E result = (E) tempNode.getElement();


     return result;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `result` variable is within the scope of the `if` block and therefore is not present outside it. Declare `result` outside the `for` loop instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
public E getFromResults(int o)
 {
     E result = null;

     Node tempNode = head;
     for(int i=1; i<= size; i++)
     {
         if(i==o)
         {
            result = (E) tempNode.getElement();
            break;
         }

         tempNode=tempNode.getNext();
     }

     return result;
 }
```

This is due to variable scope. You initialized your variable `result` from within a nested `if` statement, which itself is in a `for` statement. This means nothing outside the `if` statement can see or access your `result` variable -- ie. it is `local` to that code block.

If you were to move the initialization of `result` to outside the `if` block but still inside the `for` block, that would make it so everything inside both the `for` and `if` blocks can use it, however you still could not `return` the `result` variable since the return statement is outside both blocks.

Sometimes you will use variable scope to your advantage, ie. if a block of code requires some variable that are temporary and/or should never be accessed from outside the code block.

Answer (score 0):

You must put the variable declaration outside the loop and if. Declare that way:

```
public E getFromResults(int o)
{
    Node tempNode = head;
    E result = null;
    for(int i=1; i<= size; i++)
    {
        if(i==o)
        {
            result = (E) tempNode.getElement();
            break;
        }

        tempNode=tempNode.getNext();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Because it is not guaranteed that it will go through the loop and if so the result variable can never exist at some point.